# How to expose services running on minikube installed in the vagrant box?

Tags: proxy, vagrant, kubernetes

Infrastructure:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Host                                                 |
|     +-----------------------------------+            |
|     | Vagrant box                       |            |
|     |    +------------------------------+            |
|     |    | Minikube                     |            |
|     |    |   +--------------------------+            |
|     |    |   | Pods/Services/etc...     |            |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
|     |    |   |                          | <--+ curl  |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
|     |    |   |                          |            |
+-----+----+---+--------------------------+------------+
```

Example:

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:alpine
```

*svc.yaml*:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30888
    port: 30888
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Create the service (note its type is `NodePort`):

```
$ kubectl create -f svc.yaml
```

Everything is up and running and it seems that I'm able to connect to the `127.0.0.1:30888` and `0.0.0.0:30888` from within the `vagrant` box:

```
$ kubectl get po nginx-5bd976694-nq5sr 
NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-5bd976694-nq5sr   1/1       Running   0          9m

$ kubectl get svc nginx
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
nginx     NodePort   10.105.135.126   <none>        30888:30888/TCP   9m

$ curl -sv 127.0.0.1:30888 > /dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:30888/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 30888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:30888
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.13.8
< Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 11:18:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Dec 2017 18:18:51 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5a42928b-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
{ [612 bytes data]
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

$ curl -sv 0.0.0.0:30888 > /dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: 0.0.0.0:30888/
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 30888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:30888
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.13.8
< Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 11:18:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Dec 2017 18:18:51 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5a42928b-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
{ [612 bytes data]
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 0.0.0.0 left intact
```

So this works on the guest machine, however if I try `curl` on the `vagrant` host - there's no answer:

```
$ vagrant port | grep guest
    22 (guest) => 2222 (host)
 30270 (guest) => 27017 (host)
 30888 (guest) => 30888 (host)
 30330 (guest) => 3306 (host)
 30080 (guest) => 8080 (host)
 30081 (guest) => 8081 (host)

$ curl -sv 127.0.0.1:30888 > /dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:30888/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 30888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:30888
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 

$ curl -sv 0.0.0.0:30888 > /dev/null
* Rebuilt URL to: 0.0.0.0:30888/
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 30888 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:30888
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

I think the biggest problem here is that `minukube` ip in the vagrant box is `127.0.0.1`:

```
$ sudo -E minikube ip
127.0.0.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: forwarded ports on vagrant should be available on all ips in the host try `curl  0.0.0.0:30888`

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin Added `curl -sv 0.0.0.0:30888` to the question to show that it doesn't work.

Comment: it seems to connect in all cases but nginx does not send anything - same result with wget?

Comment: Yes, it does not work with `wget` either. It's not `Nginx` that's not returning, based on `Nginx` logs it has no idea that someone has requested something. I tried to listen with `netcat -4 -lp 30888` and I saw `curl` passing through, so it definitely has something to do with `minikube` inner workings...

Answer (score 0):

It could be necessary run with --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 option.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39586

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that a simple `iptables` rule may end the misery:

```
# iptables -A DOCKER -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a reverse ssh tunnel into the vagrant guest:

```
ssh -fN -L 30100:192.168.49.2:30100 -i ~/Vagrant\ Machines/kubernetes-dev01/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_desktop/private_key kubernetes@192.168.56.212
```

Where:

`-f` forks to background

`-N` Do not execute a remote command.

`30100` is the port on your laptop to use to bind locally, i.e. end result, go to localhost:30100 in webbrowser

`192.168.49.2` is the ip inside the vagrant machine running the app, and it runs on 30100 on the inside as well.

`-i` is the identity private ssh key path

`kubernetes` is the user who can access the vagrant machine
192.168.56.212 is the ip the laptop can connect to the vagrant machine over.

There is probably a better way to cross map the port, but this will at least give you a down and dirty way to reverse tunnel into the service.